# How to access usercontrol's values from page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Hi I've created user control named test.ascs with one textbox. Now I added this user control in my default.aspx page. How can i access that textbox value from my default.aspx page?

is there any chance?

Answer (score 7):

I usually expose the textbox's text property directly in test.ascx code behind like this:

```
public string Text
{
    get { return txtBox1.Text; }
    set { txtBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

Then you can get and set that textbox from the code behind of default.aspx like:

```
usrControl.Text = "something";
var text = usrControl.Text;
```

Answer (score 4):

From your default page try to find the TextBox using your user control.

```
TextBox myTextBox = userControl.FindControl("YourTextBox") as TextBox;
string text = myTextBox.text;
```

Comment: This method may well work, but it smells big time. You've got textbox IDs hard coded. You are not checking that the result is != null before trying to access its properties. Using FindControl is so much slower and inefficient than doing it in a proper OO fashioned way and exposing the properties on the user control.

Answer (score 3):

If this is the purpose of the control, then create a public property on your user control that exposes this value, you can then access that from your page:

```
string textBoxValue = myUserControl.GetTheValue;
```

Comment: Where `myUserControl` is ID of UserControl in markup: `<uc:MyUserControl runat="server" ID="myUserControl" />`

Answer (score 2):

How to access the value of a textbox from an USERCONTROL in a page which is using this usercontrol

step 1: in user control make an event handler

```
public event EventHandler evt;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtTest.Text = "text123";
        evt(this, e);
    }
```

2: in page call the eventhandler

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userCntrl.evt += new EventHandler(userCntrl_evt);
    }

void userCntrl_evt(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)userCntrl.FindControl("txtTest");
        string s = txt.Text;
    }
```